# djangoで複数の入力を受け取れない

Tags: python, django

djangoで掲示板サイトの検索機能を作ろうとしてます。
base.htmlで入力を受け付け、views.pyで複数の入力を受け取ろうとしていますが、うまく受け取れません。

#### やったこと

querysetがしっかり動くことは確認しました
個人的にbase.htmlの記述が間違っているのではないかと思っています。

原因がわかる方がいましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

---

#### 現状のコード

base.html

```
<section class="main__function">

<!-- select -->
<section class="select">
    <div class="select__inner">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'threads:searchtag' %}">
        <h2 class="select__title select__game">Select me</h2>
        <div class="select__radio">
        <div class="form-check select__check">
            <img src='' alt="">
            <input class="form-check-input select__game__input" type="radio" name="selectme" id="Selection 1">
            <label class="form-check-label select__game__label" for="Selection 1">
            Select 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check select__check">
            <img src='' alt="">
            <input class="form-check-input select__game__input" type="radio" name="selectme" id="Selection 2">
            <label class="form-check-label select__game__label" for="Selection 2">
            Select 2
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check select__check">
            <img src='' alt="">
            <input class="form-check-input select__game__input" type="radio" name="selectme" id="Selection 3">
            <label class="form-check-label select__game__label" for="Selection 3">
            Select 3
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="select__title">Select tag</h2>
        <div class="select__option">
        <div class="select__wrapper">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <select name="tag1" class="form-select select__select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="" selected>Select first tag...</option>
            <option value="1">Game content</option>
            <option value="2">Competition</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select__wrapper">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <select name="tag2" class="form-select select__select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="" selected>Select Second tag...</option>
            <option value="1">Game content</option>
            <option value="2">Competition</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="select__btn btn">
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

views.py

```
class SearchTagView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'article.html'
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = Q()
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET
       
        q1=query.get('selectgame',None)
        q2=query.get('tag1',None)
        q3=query.get('tag2',None)
        
        queryset = queryset.filter(
             Q(game_title__icontains=q1),Q(tag1=q2) , Q(tag2=q3))

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

なにがどう受け取れないのでしょうか？？

みるかぎり selectgame の入力欄はないようにみえます。